# Business days between two dates excluding holidays in python

Tags: python, date

I am currently using

```
np.busday_count(day1, day2))
```

to count the number of business days between two dates. How do I exclude holidays that are on business days?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of v0.14 you can use holiday calendars

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
day1 = '2010-01-01'
day2 = '2010-01-15'
us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

print(pd.DatetimeIndex(start=day1,end=day2, freq=us_bd))
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-04', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07',
           '2010-01-08', '2010-01-11', '2010-01-12', '2010-01-13',
           '2010-01-14', '2010-01-15'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```

To get the count of days use len

```
print(len(pd.DatetimeIndex(start=day1,end=day2, freq=us_bd)))
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: `start` and `end` arguments to `pd.DatetimeIndex` have now been dropped. Please use `pd.date_range(start=day1, end=day2, freq=us_bd)` instead