# How to add business days to date in python?

Tags: python, date

How can I calculate the resulting date of adding a given number of business days to a date in python?  For example: I have a start date of Jan 11, 2018 and I want to know the date that is 115 business days later (so excluding weekends and holidays).

Comment: _US federal holidays_ This isn't a coding question; it's politics.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you could probably make a `list` of federal holidays, then `while` loop through the days that you're adding to check whether they're in that list or whether they're a weekend. If either is true, don't count it. One of the key skills in programming is learning how to turn your problem into an algorithm. Show us what you've got so far, pseudo-code would be perfect, and we'll help.

Comment: Are you okay using a another library to help make the calculation?

Comment: Actually this may help out as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822697/business-days-between-two-dates-excluding-holidays-in-python

Comment: from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar.     It is a coding question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works well enough. Not the quickest or cleanest solution, but easy to understand, and doesn't use any external libraries:

```
#date_calculator.py
import datetime as dt

def add_working_days(start_date, added_days):
    # data from https://www.redcort.com/us-federal-bank-holidays/
    federal_holidays = [dt.date(2018, 1, 1), dt.date(2018, 1, 15),
        dt.date(2018, 2, 19), dt.date(2018, 5, 28), dt.date(2018, 7, 4),
        dt.date(2018, 9, 3), dt.date(2018, 10, 8), dt.date(2018, 11, 12),
        dt.date(2018, 11, 22), dt.date(2018, 12, 25)]

    days_elapsed = 0
    while days_elapsed < added_days:
        test_date = start_date+dt.timedelta(days=1)
        start_date = test_date
        if test_date.weekday()>4 or test_date in federal_holidays:
            # if a weekend or federal holiday, skip
            continue
        else:
            # if a workday, count as a day
            days_elapsed += 1

    return start_date

print(add_working_days(dt.date(2018, 1, 11), 10))
#> 2018-01-26
print(add_working_days(dt.date(2018, 1, 11), 115))
#> 2018-06-26
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Exactly what i NEEDED.