# How to get list of business dates given month and year in Python?

Tags: python, list, datetime

I'm trying to obtain a list of dates (in datetime format) for any given month and year in Python.
ie. if month is August or 8 and year is 2019,
my expected list would be something like this:
list = [2019-08-01, 2019-08-02, 2019-08-05, .....] (as you can see, I'd need the weekends to not show up)

No need to worry about any holiday assumptions!

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822697/business-days-between-two-dates-excluding-holidays-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
from calendar import monthrange
import datetime
year=2020
month = 8
days = monthrange(year, month)[1]
date_list=[]
for day in range(1,days+1):
    a = datetime.date(year,month,day)
    if a.weekday()<5:
        date_list.append(str(a))
```

**output**

```
print(date_list)
['2020-08-03',
 '2020-08-04',
 '2020-08-05',
 '2020-08-06',
 '2020-08-07',
 '2020-08-10',
 '2020-08-11',
 '2020-08-12',
 '2020-08-13',
 '2020-08-14',
 '2020-08-17',
 '2020-08-18',
 '2020-08-19',
 '2020-08-20',
 '2020-08-21',
 '2020-08-24',
 '2020-08-25',
 '2020-08-26',
 '2020-08-27',
 '2020-08-28',
 '2020-08-31']
```